# What exactly pushes a fallen object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision, free-body-diagram

If an object falls and hit the ground with a force, the ground also pushes it back because of third law of motion but from where does the force coming in the ground particles and they are also pushed downwards at the same time due to force of object. So what actually applies force to the fallen object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object consists of atoms composed of charges (electrons and protons). Likewise, the ground is as well. As the object hits the ground, the atoms in the ground are displaced and pushed closer together. The electrons in the atoms begin to repel each other and therefore resist this compression and as a consequence your object is then pushed by the atoms in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

We know of four different types of forces: strong nuclear forces, electromagnetic forces, weak nuclear forces, and gravitational forces.  I believe the force from the ground on the object is electrical repulsion from the electrons in the atoms of the ground and the object being pushed closer together during the collision.  A theoretical physicist can probably elaborate.

Comment: Not electron it is proton repulsion or nucleus nucleus repulsion

Comment: The atomic scale (where electrons interact) is where the repulsion occurs, not the nuclear scale.  The atomic scale is about $10^-10$  m,  the nuclear scale is about $10^-14$ m.  For collisions of the type here the nucleus is not involved

Comment: How can you say that

Comment: electrons are distributed over the wholeatom

Comment: so it shouldn't be possible for them to create a good repulsion. Do you have any other argument.?

Comment: The electrons closest to the interacting objects interact. There is insufficient energy to push the objects beyond where the electrons interact. Also, see answers from others.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe i was thinking wrong.